# Can anyone tell me what this means please? I think it is a proverb

Tags: traditional-characters, literary-chinese, old-chinese, proverb

A friend left me this at work, I think it is a proverb but Google gave me different translations each time which confused me as none of it made sense.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

From *Tao Te Ching* ("Canon of morality") attributed to Laozi. These words are excerpted from various parts. Various translation exists, and here I am just being literal.

上善若水。水善利萬物而不爭。(part 8)
The utmost goodness [or benevolence] is like the water. Water is good at being benevolent to everything, and does not compete with them.

守靜篤。(part 16)
It is concrete to hold stillness.
[or better, "Surely you must be calm."

靜爲躁君。(part 26)
Stillness is the monarch of the movement.
[Or better, "The waiting person rules the impatient person."]

清靜為天下正。(part 45)
Stilness is the right thing of the world.
[Or maybe "Inactivity is the principle of reigning."]

It seems your friend admires Lauzi very much ; )

Comment: @Safeen then up-vote it

Comment: @user3306356 Safeen can't upvote the answer, since (s)he doesn't have 15 reputation points. However, (s)he can accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: @wythagoras Three upvotes for this question will give them the points they need - I took care of the first up-vote.

Comment: I just gave the third.